# jqxwidgets jqxtree drag drop issue

Tags: jquery, jqxwidgets

I have tried two trees whose data is loaded from json. Whenever I use json load drag and drop is not working as expected. The event is always taking the second tree.

I try to Drag an element from TreeA but its taking the element from TreeB .You can see which one is being dragged from the labels displayed under the tree

If there is no respective element in TreeB as in TreeA then TreeA element is getting dragged

I couldn't figure it out. I think some thing has to do with the object which is storing only second tree data..Any help would be appreciated :)

Below is the fiddle demo of the same

http://jsfiddle.net/tgb1ecLx/

```
function source(data) {
    var source = {
        datatype: "json",
        datafields: [{
            name: 'id'
        }, {
            name: 'parentid'
        }, {
            name: 'text'
        }, {
            name: 'value'
        }, {
            name: 'expanded'
        }],
        id: 'id',

        localdata: data
    };
    // create data adapter.
    dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
    // perform Data Binding.
    dataAdapter.dataBind();
    // get the tree items. The first parameter is the item's id. The second parameter is the parent item's id. The 'items' parameter represents 
    // the sub items collection name. Each jqxTree item has a 'label' property, but in the JSON data, we have a 'text' field. The last parameter 
    // specifies the mapping between the 'text' and 'label' fields.  
    var records = dataAdapter.getRecordsHierarchy('id', 'parentid', 'items', [{
        name: 'text',
        map: 'label'
    }]);
    // if(tree="fact")
    $('#treeA').jqxTree({
        source: records
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem which the drag & drop function is that can not differentiate between the two treeviews.

I increased all ID values ​​to one hundred. (on the Data for TreeB) Now the assignments were completed correctly.

I hope this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/tgb1ecLx/10/

```
 data = [
                    { "id": "102",
                        "parentid": "101",
                        "text": "Tree B Hot Chocolate",
                        "value": "$2.3"
                    }, {
                        "id": "103",
                        "parentid": "101",
                        "text": "Tree B Peppermint Hot Chocolate",
                        "value": "$2.3"
                    }, {
                        "id": "104",
                        "parentid": "101",
                        "text": "Tree B Salted Caramel Hot Chocolate",
                        "value": "$2.3"
                    }, {
                        "id": "105",
                        "parentid": "101",
                        "text": " Tree B White Hot Chocolate",
                        "value": "$2.3"
                    }, {
                        "text": "Tree B Chocolate Beverage",
                        "id": "101",
                        "parentid": "-1",
                        "value": "$2.3"
                }
                        ];
```